# Allow only few characters with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to use `preg_match` to allow only few characters, more exactly, I want to allow only these characters: `a-z A-Z 0-9 . , ( ) @ # ! ?`

How can I do that with `preg_replace`, to check if text contains more than these characters or not?

Comment: Which regular expressions have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all characters from a string except the ones you've indicated, you can use:

```
$sanitized = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\(\)@#!?]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: What's with all the commas in the character class? It should just be `[^a-zA-Z0-9.,()@#!?]`. Commas don't have a special meaning inside character classes, they are not separating characters.

Comment: I'm not sure about the preg_replace. This won't check, if the string contains only given pattern, instead, it will replace it.

Comment: Well, I don't want to remove other characters, I want to check if string contains other characters, then if string contain other characters, system will return error (I will use if {} else {}, but I know to do that, I need help with preg_match).

Answer (score 2):

In order to test if your sting contains invalid characters, you could do:

```
if ( preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.,()@#!?]/', $string) )
    echo 'At least ONE invalid character found!';
```

I'm not sure I well understand what you want, but here are some regex that you can use:

```
if ( preg_match('/^[^a-zA-Z0-9.,()@#!?]+$/', $string) )
    echo 'All characters are invalid!';

if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()@#!?]+$/', $string) )
    echo 'All characters are valid!';
```

Comment: The problem is that if there are other characters, will return true. I want to use it to return false when other characters are detected in string.

Comment: @Bogdan: You want to test if ALL the characters are invalid? Am I understanding well?

Comment: I want to check in a string if there are other characters than these characters, for example, if in a string is this character: ~
If there are other characters, I want to return false, else I want to return true (if in a string are only characters from my list).